# Cordova camera is activated only when app moves into background

Tags: javascript, objective-c, camera, cordova-plugins, window.location

I am trying to include the cordova camera plugin for an iPad app, but after invoking the camera using navigator.camera, it shows on the screen only after the app has gone to the background (tapping the home button). However, this occurs only if I am listening to the webView: shouldStartLoadWithRequest event, which I am using as a javascript-Objective C bridge.

Versions used:

- Cordova: 5.4.1
- iOS platform/platform specific cordova.js: 4.1.1
- Xcode: 7.2

Steps to set up project:

- cordova create pluginTest com.pluginTest pluginTest
- cd pluginTest
- cordova platform add ios
- cordova plugin add cordoba-plugin-camera

To test the camera, I have edited the index.js file, which was generated by cordova so that the onDeviceReady function looks like:

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    alert(navigator.camera);
    navigator.camera.getPicture(function(imageData) {
        alert('success');
    },
    function(message) {
        alert('fail');
    });
}
```

This seems to work fine, and the camera pops up after the alert.

But in MainViewController.m, if I am listening for a webView: shouldStartLoadWithRequest event like:

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest: (NSURLRequest *)request navigationType: (UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    NSString* req = [[request URL] absoluteString];
    NSLog(req);

    return YES;
}
```

Then, once the app loads, the first location change is the index.html, after which - once navigator.camera.getPicture is executed - there is an infinite number of location changes hitting the above method, and url is always 'gap://ready'. Once the home button is tapped, the flow of requests stop, and the camera shows up. Any ideas why this could be happening?

Also, I had to have my MainViewController conform to the UIWebViewDelegate protocol for it to actually listen for the shouldStartLoadWithRequest event, in case I was using a 4.1.1 cordova.js. In this case, merely conforming to the UIWebViewDelegate protocol was enough for the issue to occur. Oddly, if I were using an older platform of cordova - 3.9.2 specifically - then it seems that CDVViewController is already listening for the shouldStartLoadWithRequest event. In either case the camera shows up after app suspension.

The console trace in Xcode shows:

```
2016-05-04 19:02:51.015 plugTest2[3949:2271226] file:///var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/FE21DCB1-7ADE-4754-80F1- 7055F8E1F450/plugTest2.app/www/index.html
2016-05-04 19:02:51.020 plugTest2[3949:2271226] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2016-05-04 19:02:51.759 plugTest2[3949:2271226] Finished load of: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/FE21DCB1-7ADE-4754-80F1-7055F8E1F450/plugTest2.app/www/index.html
2016-05-04 19:02:57.149 plugTest2[3949:2271226] gap://ready
```

Followed by about a hundred 'gap://ready' urls in the next 4 seconds...

```
2016-05-04 19:03:01.738 plugTest2[3949:2271226] gap://ready
2016-05-04 19:03:02.112 plugTest2[3949:2271226] Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.
```

Answer (score 1):

I know I arrived late, but today I had a tough day trying to figure this out, and I could fix this issue adding the following to my Content Security Policy tag:

```
default-src * blob: 'self' gap:
```

I put you in context. This is the meta tag in the index.html of my web app.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * blob: 'self' gap:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' (…)/ >
```

I found information about the problem in [this](http://www.qed42.com/blog/ionic-iOS10-compatibility-csp) article. As it explains:

> “gap://ready file://* : is required to allow the loading of remote
>   content in iOS 10 app”

I hope this is helpful to someone else.

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work for me. I wasn't using any framework - just the default cordova app, so all my scripts were loaded from the filesystem anyways and I had the self attribute on my CSP meta tag.

I ended up writing a plugin to handle whatever was in the shouldStartLoadWithRequest block.